# Angular 2 syntax helpers for Angular 1.2

Tags: angularjs, angular

My application is in angular version 1.2. We are planning to make any new changes using typescript and angular 2 syntax helpers (like [ng-metadata](https://github.com/ngParty/ng-metadata) or [angular2-now](https://github.com/pbastowski/angular2-now))

Unfortunately the above syntax helpers only works for angular version 1.4+. Is there any such helpers available for angular 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

try this [Angular-Typescript](https://github.com/ulfryk/angular-typescript) project on github, and my advice is to updated your project to 1.4 or above to make it easier for you!